# Changing a TextBox.Text outside of the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the Text of TextBox bound to a property in my ViewModel class like so:

```
Text="{Binding Display, Mode=OneWay}"
```

The problem is I need to format the Text of TextBox without changing the backing Display property in the ViewModel (I need to maintain the precision in the string). I could create another property in the ViewModel, but changing it in the View class seems a little cleaner to me. The problem is, after the first time the Text is updated from the View class, the data binding is lost, and no further updates happen.

How do I reinstate the data binding after manipulating the Text property, getting it ready for the next time the Display property changes?

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        const int maxForDisplay = 12;
        TextBox _display = sender as TextBox;
        if (_display.Text.Length > maxForDisplay)
        {
            _display.Text = _display.Text.Substring(0, maxForDisplay);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that almost imply that your `Mode=OneWay` in regards to `Binding` would need to be `TwoWay`?

Comment: Another inteperation of your question is that the you should have a View Model between the View and the Model, and its the View Model that should do the formatting stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do stuff like that.

If you need to `format` the output in the TextBox differently - use the `Converter`, e.g.

```
Text="{Binding Display, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}"
```

(converter also supports converting `back`, so from your entered values into Display - e.g. not sure if that's what you want but you can add extra formatting when outputting to screen, and remove it when 'storing' back to property)

Or if, where possible just use the `{Binding Display, StringFormat=...}"`